# Multiple search form using functions and if else

Tags: php, mysql, function, if-statement

Hi Im creating a multiple search form using PHP,HTML,SQL with the use of functions, for example I have 3 search fields Firstname, lastname and email. I would let the user input from any of those, therefore i would be needing the if else statement, but to be able to satisfy all conditions it would take a lot of if else, so i think of using a function to output the table and place it inside the if else after the query on the database. But it seems that it could not be able to search in the database if I do it like this it outputs "0 results", but if i remove the function and place it on the end of my script I am able to search in the db but it could not detect my else condition which is "You have not yet entered any values"

```
    function checkres()
    {
    //Get query on the database
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        //Check results
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
        //Headers
            echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Image ID</th>"; 
        echo "<th>Lastname</th>";
        echo "<th>Firstname</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>PhoneNumber</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

      //output data of each row
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['LastName']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['FirstName']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['PhoneNumber']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

            }
                  echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
    }

   if (!empty($sfname) && empty($slname) && empty($semail) )
{
     $sql = "select * from Userlist where FirstName LIKE '%". $sfname  ."%'" ;

checkres();

}

 else  if (!empty($sfname) && !empty($slname) && empty($semail))

{
  $sql = "select * from Userlist where FirstName LIKE '%". $sfname  ."%' AND LastName LIKE '%". %slname. "%'";

checkres();

}

else
{
   echo "You have not yet entered any values ";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

This is the new one

```
<form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform">
      First Name:<br>
          <input  type="text" name="fname">
      <br>Last Name:<br>
          <input type="text" name="lname">
      <br>Email: <br>
          <input type="text" name="email">
      <br>
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
<?php
$sfname = $_POST["fname"];
$slname = $_POST["lname"];
$semail = $_POST["email"];
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


function checkres()
    {
    //Get query on the database
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        //Check results
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
        //Headers
            echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Image ID</th>"; 
        echo "<th>Lastname</th>";
        echo "<th>Firstname</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>PhoneNumber</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

      //output data of each row
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            echo "<tr>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['LastName']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['FirstName']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
                      echo "<td>".$row['PhoneNumber']."</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";

            }
                  echo "</table>";
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
    }

if(!empty($sfname) || !empty($slname) || !empty($semail)){



$emailQueryPart = !empty($semail) ? "Email LIKE '%$semail%'" : "";
    $lastnameQueryPart = !empty($slname) ? "LastName LIKE '%$slname%'" : "";
    $firstnameQueryPart = !empty($sfname) ? "FirstName LIKE '%$sfname%'" : "";

        $arr = array($emailQueryPart, $lastnameQueryPart,$firstnameQueryPart);


        $sql = "select * from Userlist";

        for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){

            if(!empty($arr[$i])){

                if($i > 0){
                    $sql.= " AND ".$arr[$i];
                }else{
                    $sql.= " WHERE ".$arr[$i];
                }
            }
        }

    }else{
        echo "You must enter at least one value";
    }

checkres();
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is in my opinion a little bit confusing (and a little bit odd n terms of the program's flow structure).
You can simply use an array of variables for your input fields and then loop through the array to generate your SQL statement. So your HTML form would look like this:

```
<form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform">
  First Name:<br />
  <input  type="text" name="queryArray[FirstName]" />
  <br />Last Name:<br />
  <input type="text" name="queryArray[LastName]" />
  <br />Email:<br />
  <input type="text" name="queryArray[Email]" />
  <br />
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

A more clear structure would be if you define these 2 functions, which of course can be placed anywhere in your PHP code block:

```
function createSql($queryArray) {
  if (is_array($queryArray)) {
    $sql = null;
    foreach ($queryArray as $key => $value) {
      if ($value != null ) {
      $addQuery = "`".$key."` LIKE '%".$value."%'";
      if ($sql == null)
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Userlist` WHERE ".$addQuery;
      else
        $sql = $sql." AND ".$addQuery;
    }
    return $sql;
  }
}

function checkres($sql) {
  // Create connection
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  // Check connection
  if (!$conn)
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

  //Get query on the database
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  //Check results
  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    //Headers
    echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>";
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Image ID</th>"; 
        echo "<th>Lastname</th>";
        echo "<th>Firstname</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>PhoneNumber</th>";
      echo "</tr>";

    //output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['LastName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['FirstName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$row['PhoneNumber']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
  } else
      echo "0 results";

  // Close connection
  mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Finally you will have to call the functions according to user activity:

```
if ($_POST != null) {
  $sql = createSql($_POST[queryArray]);
  checkres($sql);
}
```

An example how the SQL generation works is listed [here](http://main.xfiddle.com/a72ab950/test.php)

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors:

```
$sql = "select * from Userlist where FirstName LIKE '%". $sfname  ."%' AND LastName LIKE '%". %slname. "%'";
```

You have %slname instead of $slname.

Another mistake is in the program flow. Your else condition, which is saying :"You have not yet entered any values" will be reached in two cases:

1. When all fields are left blank
2. When all fields are filled with values.

You don't want that. You have to improve your logic, and build a query based on that, and that can be done like this:

```
    function checkres()
{
    //Get query on the database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    //Check results
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        //Headers
        echo "<table border='1' style='width:100%'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Image ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Lastname</th>";
        echo "<th>Firstname</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>PhoneNumber</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

        //output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['LastName']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['FirstName']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$row['PhoneNumber']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}

if(!empty($sfname) || !empty($slname) || !empty($semail)){

    $emailQueryPart = !empty($semail) ? "Email LIKE '$semail'" : "";
    $lastnameQueryPart = !empty($slname) ? "LastName LIKE '%$slname%'" : "";
    $firstnameQueryPart = !empty($sfname) ? "FirstName LIKE '%$sfname%'" : "";

    $arr = array($emailQueryPart, $lastnameQueryPart,$firstnameQueryPart);


    $sql = "select * from Userlist";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr); $i++){

        if(!empty($arr[$i])){

            if($i > 0){
                $sql.= " AND ".$arr[$i];
            }else{
                $sql.= " WHERE ".$arr[$i];
            }
        }
    }

}else{
    echo "You must enter at least one value";
}

checkres();
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: thanks for this, i have to change the echo $sql and place the $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

Comment: You are welcome... Yes, you just have to execute it now. Replace your  part code (if-else if statements) and run your checkers function.

Comment: Im sorry, im a bit confused (im very noob at this) i cant seem to search in the database, could you check the code that i have placed with your code above? I have edited my post

Comment: I edited my answer. Copy and paste now. Probably you couldn't search db table because of missing % signs with LIKE statement.

Comment: It seems that i could still not search in the db, even if i did this '%$semail%' it just returns 0 results

Comment: You have to keep in mind that query is based on $sfname, $slname and $semail variables. I suppose those are correctly handled , because I can't see how do you initalize them. Enable your error reporting, put at the beginning of the script this line error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Also where do you initialize your db connection - $conn variable?

Comment: I have edited my post and included the upper scripts on how i initialize the variables and connect to the db

Comment: Everything seems fine. What I can think of, is to check column names in your table and column names in your query.

Comment: I've checked and verified im pretty sure its correct and this is also working in a simple version without the if else statements where i query something on the db and it shows the table

Comment: I've also noticed that when there is no query it shows this "You must enter at least one value0 results "

Comment: There is no query if there is no search terms. That should be correct. But I have no more ideas why that doesn't work.

Comment: I mean it should only show "You must enter at least one value" and not add the 0 results which is the echo for the else statement inside my function

Comment: i have echo this and this output select * from Userlist AND FirstName LIKE '%test%'

Comment: there's something wrong on the echo output, the result should be "select * from Userlist WHERE FirstName LIKE '%test%'